# How to check if TextArea input is string

Tags: java, swing, jtextarea, japplet, numberformatexception

So I have a TextArea that's supposed to take in a number that I will then parse as an integer. However, if the input is not a number, then I need to use my try catch for a NumberFormatException. My try catch is recognizing and showing my error message, but I am unable to suppress my console showing error messages.

```
String textPNum = projNumber.getText();
try {
  input = Integer.parseInt(textPNum);
} catch (NumberFormatException e) {
  redText.setText("Please enter a numeric value for project number and initial funding");
}`
```

Here is my console error:

https://gyazo.com/af512a1f2b819d5ed88e353b460a360f

Comment: *"Here is my console error:"* Don't post (links to) *screenshots* of the console, copy/paste the text!

Comment: BTW - given Swing, use a `JSpinner` with a `SpinnerNumberModel` instead. Easier for you and the user.

Comment: Suppress the console to what end? If you are catching the exception and doing something with it then just don't print the stack trace and nothing will print to the console. What is the problem? Also, a text area is a poor choice for this as stated above.

Answer (score -1):

If you try to parse an integer out of a string with more than just numbers, you will get NaN

```
+"sdf" === NaN
```

You can use window.isNaN to check if an integer was not parsed from a string

```
window.isNaN(Integer.parseInt(textPNum));
```

Comment: This is irrelevant to the question.